# In which vlan am I in?

Tags: vlan

**My question:** are there any methods to detect that in which vlan I am? Can tcpdump show this? Or can I force a GENERAL switch to say to me?

Comment: It depends on VLAN configuration. If your system has been configured to add VLAN tag to all packets doing `tcpdump -vvv -U -l -n -e -i any` is enough. If your system is seemingly connected to regular ethernet and the switch tags the packets for routing, there's no way to know about it without querying the info from the switch (using manufacturer dependant tools with switch specific authentication).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by a GENERAL switch, but for most switches it is impossible to see in which VLAN you are when you are connected to an 'access' port.

That said, using the CDP (Cisco) and LLDP (Juniper) protocols you *can* find out in which VLAN you are. Enabling CDP/LLDP on an access port is arguably a security risk (information exposure) so it might not be enabled on your network. You can use tcpdump to disassemble CDP/LLDP packets to find the VLAN number.

For Cisco CDP:

```
sudo tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000'
```

For Juniper LLDP:

```
sudo tcpdump -nn -v -i eth0 -s 1500 -c 1 '(ether[12:2]=0x88cc or ether[20:2]=0x2000)'
```

Comment: good one. this add pipe to grep gives just the basics for quick reference. running from Mac OS X.  `tcpdump -nn -v -i en4 -s 1500 -c 1 'ether[20:2] == 0x2000' | grep -E 'Device|Port|VLAN' `

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, from a client computer, you cannot tell which vlan you're in.  You can look at an IP address and subnet mask and determine which subnet the IP is in, but not the vlan.  However, the [wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/VLAN) has some interesting information about capturing vlan tags off the wire.

> When capturing on a VLAN, you won't necessarily see the VLAN tags in
>   packets.
>
> For example, in at least some operating systems, you might have more
>   than one network interface device on which you can capture - a "raw
>   interface" corresponding to the physical network adapter, and a "VLAN
>   interface" the traffic on which has had the VLAN tags removed. The
>   OS's networking stack would be connected to the VLAN interface, and
>   that interface would appear to the networking stack to be an Ethernet
>   interface with a smaller MTU than normal (to leave room for the VLAN
>   tags). On those OSes, in order to see the raw Ethernet packets, rather
>   than "de-VLANized" packets, you would have to capture not on the
>   virtual interface for the VLAN, but on the interface corresponding to
>   the physical network device, if possible.
>
> Here are some details on capturing VLAN tags on various operating
>   systems. If the OS or the network adapter driver won't allow the VLAN
>   tags to be captured, set up port mirroring (or "port spanning", as
>   Cisco calls it) on the VLAN switch and connect an independent system,
>   such as a laptop, to the mirror port, and don't configure the
>   interface attached to that port as a member of a VLAN.. You'll
>   definitely see the VLAN tags, regardless of what OS the independent
>   system is running or what type of network adapter you're using.
>
> Linux
>
> To enable VLAN tagging, you need two things: the vlan rpm (e.g.,
>   vlan-1.8-23) and the 8021q kernel module. Once installed, the vconfig
>   command can be used to create VLAN interfaces on an existing physical
>   device. For more info, see the vconfig(8) man page.
>
> After your VLAN interfaces are set up and traffic is flowing, you can
>   run Wireshark and capture on the VLAN interface of your choice (e.g.,
>   eth0.100 for VLAN 100) or on the underlying physical interface (e.g.,
>   eth0). If you choose the former, you will only see frames destined for
>   that VLAN; if you choose the latter, you may see all frames or you may
>   see only untagged frames (if there are any). It depends on the NIC,
>   the NIC firmware, the driver, and the alignment of the moon and
>   planets. (A table enumerating the behaviors of various adapters,
>   firmware versions, and drivers might be useful. -Guy Harris)
>
> If you are capturing on the host system where the VLANs are
>   configured, you will probably not see the VLAN tags in the captured
>   frames -- even if you capture on the physical device. The driver is
>   stripping the tags before the pcap library sees them. See the tech
>   note from Intel mentioned in the Windows section below. (Do Linux
>   drivers support getting VLAN tags, perhaps with a driver configuration
>   option or other option, in the same way that the Intel Windows driver
>   does? -Guy Harris) (e100 driver works great on 2.4.26 - Jaap Keuter)
>
> Windows
>
> Windows has no built-in support mechanisms for VLANs. There aren't
>   separate physical and VLAN interfaces you can capture from, unless a
>   specialized driver that adds such support is present.
>
> So whether you see VLAN tags in Wireshark or not will depend on the
>   network adapter you have and on what its and its driver do with VLAN
>   tags.
>
> Most "simple" network adapters (e.g. widely used Realtek RTL 8139) and
>   their drivers will simply pass VLAN tags to the upper layer to handle
>   these. In that case, Wireshark will see VLAN tags and can handle and
>   show them.
>
> Some more sophisticated adapters will handle VLAN tags in the adapter
>   and/or the driver. This includes some Intel adapters and, as far as i
>   know, Broadcom gigabit chipsets (NetXtreme / 57XX based chips).
>   Moreover, it is likely that cards that have specialized drivers will
>   follow this path as well, to prevent interference from the "real"
>   driver.

Answer (score 2):

lldpd package is probably the best solution.

```
lldpctl
```

the downside to lldpd is it sends out ARP requests using a hardcoded MAC address. If you install it across multiple machines on the same switch, it would appear like a "mac spoofing" scenario. Processing such packets has its own overhead which will start spiking your switch's CPU.

Answer (score 1):

VLans can be defined by network hardware (routers or level 3 switches) and are invisible to the client. You'll have to look on the switch or router.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you run `ifconfig -a` it will show you the device that's the tap for the VLAN. From my understanding the VLAN ID is the suffix portion of the interface's name.

For example if your system contains an ethernet device, `eth0`, any VLAN IDs associated through this interface would have a corresponding suffix with the VLAN's ID after it, something like `eth0.192`. See this reference titled: [9.2.6. Setting Up 802.1q VLAN Tagging](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_802.1q-vlan-tagging.html) for additional information & examples.

Using `tcpdump` and assuming the packet contains a 802.1q VLAN tag, you can do the following:

```
$ tcpdump -s0 -nnpi eth0 vlan 100
```

where 100 is the vlan id.

**NOTE:** The 2nd link in the references section has a full example showing the setup and interrogation using `tcpdump` for a home network setup using 802.1Q.

#### References

- [HowTo: Configure Linux Virtual Local Area Network (VLAN)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html)
- [802.1Q VLAN trunk in Linux](http://myhomelab.blogspot.com/2014/01/8021q-vlan-trunk-in-linux.html)

Comment: This shows the VLAN only if the interface and switchport are configured to use tagged VLAN. If the switchport is a normal access port, the VLAN assignment is made on the switch, and the VLAN cannot be seen from the traffic.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen - correct, that's the 802.1Q as I understand it. If that's not the case then it's impossible to see the VLAN IDs, since they're stripped off prior to being delivered to the I/F. I'll also note that it is impossible to induce the switch to tell you your VLAN ID either, you'd have to have switch access to get at this info (i.e. login creds).